# EL ( ${} tags ) not working in Glassfish

Tags: jsp, glassfish, jstl, el

I'm struggling to get a webapp runnign on a local glassfish server. This server is in a 'offline' intranet.
I got the website running on glassfish 3.1 and 2.1, tried different versions. 
The web app is old, original like 7 years old. So far the only thing i cant get to work are the `${} EL`-tags. it prints them as `${}`, thus not recognizing EL at all.

Few things i tried, every solution here is pointing to it:

```
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
```

which won't work, because it can't get the urls (offline intranet). I dont know how to make this offline to work. that might be a solution?

I also tried to find out what JSP/JSTL(/EL) version is running on Glassfish, I couldnt find that either.

Thanks in advance.

ps. If you need more info, I'm happy to provide more

Comment: The xmlns URIs are not used to download anything from the given locations (they don't need to exist at all).

Comment: wow.. it was that easy. it works now, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
```

This was the right answer, even for offline applications.

Comment: What is the difference? What did you change?

Comment: It is the same, I assumed the namespaces wouldnt work for me because i work in an Offline environment. 
So it wasn't a technical issue, but an assumption issue.